# Variable amplitude sinusoid in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I do it in Matlab to get a sinusoid which every odd peak has amplitude = 1 and every even peak has amplitude = 0.5? I have tried the following:

```
fs = 44100;
t1 = 0:(1/fs):0.1;
t2 = 0.1:(1/fs):0.2;
f = 5;

x1 = cos( 2*pi*f*t1 );
x2 = sin( 2*pi*f*t1 )-1;
x3 = cos( 2*pi*f*t2 );
x  = [ x1,x2,x3 ];
figure; plot(x)
```

But in the plot the result is not smooth, but it goes from one to another too drastically. Is there a way of "choosing" the amplitude of each peak of the sinusoid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take parts of the wave form and piece together multiple copies with different scaling factors. E.g. like this

```
fs = 44100;
f = 5;

t = 0:(1/fs):0.1;
x1 = sin(2*pi * f * t);
x = [x1, -0.5 * x1, x1, -0.5 * x1, x1, -0.5 * x1, x1, -0.5 * x1];
```

[image]

or like this

```
t = 0:(1/fs):0.2;
x1 = sin(2*pi * f * t);
x = [x1, 0.5 * x1, x1, 0.5 * x1];
```

[image]

Or you could [modulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude_modulation) the amplitude of one sine by another periodic function:

```
t = 0:(1/fs):0.8;
x1 = cos(2*pi * f * t);
x2 = (cos(2*pi * f * t) + 3) / 4;
x = x1 .* x2;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is not "a sine". It's, as you already noticed, a combination of sines.

You can easily get what you want by considering your signal in frequency domain. You get one oscillation with amplitude 1, and another oscillation of half that frequency, half that amplitude and half a period phase offset, added to it.

What you get will *not* look like you probably think (one period full amplitude, next period half amplitude) and so on.

I recommend looking at the spectrum of the signal you're generating

```
plot(abs(fft(x1)));
```

and carefully thinking about what you would have to do to achieve what you want; you can then actually make that adjustment to the

```
X1 = fft(x1);
```

vector, and get a corrected `x1_tilde` by

```
x1_tilde = ifft(x1);
```